# Scene transition does not work on scene touch andengine

Tags: touch, andengine, scene

```
setOnSceneTouchListenerBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
attachChild(splash);    
//in the scenetouch event implemented method
@Override
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown()) {
    Scene_Manager.getInstance().setScene(sceneType.MAIN_MENU);
    Scene_Manager.getInstance().createmenuScene();  
    }
    return false;
}
```

The thing is the scene does not change when I touch at the scene.

Comment: What do you have in `.setScene()` and `.createmenuScene()`. Shouldn't they be swapped (change their places)?

Comment: `public void setScene(Base_scene scene) {
  engine.setScene(scene);
  currentScene=scene;
  CurrentSceneType=scene.getSceneType();
         }
                public void createmenuScene() {
  ResourceManager.getinstance().loadMenuResources(); 
  main_menu=new Main_menu();
  currentScene=main_menu;
  setScene(sceneType.MAIN_MENU);
  disposeSplashScene();
         }`

Comment: Did you try to first create the scene and then set is as current in engine?

Comment: Yes,does that matter?But even if I change the code i the scenetoucheventListener to Log.e("Done!!","Touch");It doesn't even gives the message in logcat.That means that the touch is not even responding.

Comment: The issue has been resolved after i take a look at my activity class.The callbacks were not return on oncreateScene method and onPopulate scene method.